Is it possible to copy contents and format of a range from other sheets to the first sheet depending on a condition in cell A1 of the first sheet?
I have content on Sheet 2 and Sheet 3 in cells B1:H29 including merged cells and coloured backgrounds. I need to devise a way of copying the data and format of the content from Sheet 2 or Sheet 3 depending on the content of A1 in Sheet 1.
Have tried using the function arrayformula but this only copies the data.
